# moment-generating function

Tags: probability

The moment-generating function of a random variable $X$ is defined as 
$$M(t)=Ee^{tX}.$$
Is there any simple criteria to check if a given function is a moment-generating function of some random variable $X$ (we only care the existence and don't really try to see what random variable $X$ is). For example,

$$M(t)=e^{c\cdot t^\theta}$$
for some constant $c>0$ and $\theta>2.$ When $\theta=2,$ then a normal random variable $X$ will do; and when $\theta=1,$ then a degenerate random variable $X$ will do. How about $\theta>2$ ? Appreciate for any suggestions.

Comment: You can't expect a simple criterion ...